# Converting an Ext.data.TreeStore to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch, extjs

I need to stringify an Ext.data.TreeStore (cause I wanna save it to Local Storage), but calling Ext.encode() doesn't work -- I get a circular structure error.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Refer to the link below: This should solve your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391518/get-json-data-from-extjs-treepanel

Comment: Here is the link to the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850978/how-to-generate-a-custom-json-from-treepanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of anyway, maybe it's just not possible to save it like it is with normal store. I think your best bet is to save it item by item.